# Setting Height with Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Using Angular (and Ionic) I have a simple directive where I am trying to set the height of an inner element to match the height of its parent.

```
.directive('matchHeight', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {
      var parentHeight = elem.parent()[0].offsetHeight;
      elem.css('height', parentHeight + 'px');
    }
  };
});
```

The height that it is picking up is not the actual height of the parent though... If I inspect the height in the DOM or log the parent object and look at offsetHeight there, its different than the height that is being set. I suspect this has something to do with the timing of when the directive is being applied, which is something that totally eludes me... Anyone have any tips on this?

[Here is a codepen.](http://codepen.io/pattyok/pen/phaFB?editors=101)

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use height 100% for this?

Comment: It looks pretty same to me. I tried to change background colors and child element fills the parent. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lsKxD . Could you show a sketch of what you want or describe it better please?

Comment: If you make the size of the screen closer to the size of the phone, you can see where this is not working. Resize it so the text of the second box wraps, and refresh (codepen likes to refresh with a large window for the view so for best results open the inspector to the right of the codepen).

Comment: 100% height does not work on Chromium (Android Browser).